# How to exclude posts by ID within a category/archive loop

Tags: wp-query, categories, page-template

I would like to exclude the current "page" (not post) from a categroy loop :

files :

archive.php,
content.php,
content-top-page.php (page template)

I have created 2 categories (archive.php) and releated 2 posts to each category. I have included "content-top-page.php" at the top of the category. Those are "pages" and I don't want them to change (a title, a post thumbnail and a specific text, that's all).

The problem :

The template pages are being displayed within the loop with the other posts. The current template page of each category is being included in. I am using specific ACF variables in the template pages.

Thanks if you have some ideas.

**Archive.php**

```
$exclude_ids = array( 45, 36 );

$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'exclude' => $exclude_ids,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

));

<section style="padding:10px!important;">

    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <section>
            <?php
                get_template_part('content','top-page');

            ?>
        </section><!-- .section -->


        <div class="row">

            <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 

                <div class="col-lg-3">

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 
  get_post_format() ); 
                    ?>

                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>  


    <?php endif;

    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </section>
```

**content-top-page.php (template page)**

```
<?php if ( has_category('my_category_1') ): ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6" style="background-color:red;">
        <img src="<?php get_field('top_profil_featured_image'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php echo get_field('top_profil_content'); ?>
    </div> 

</div>

<?php endif ?>




<?php if ( has_category('my_category_2') ): ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6" style="background-color:green;">
        <img src="<?php get_field('top_profil_featured_image'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php echo get_field('top_profil_content'); ?>
    </div> 

</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

**content.php**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="" <?php post_class(); ?> style="border:1px solid #6f3fa5;">

<?php 
    if ( !is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <div class="entry-img">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-way-common'); ?></a>
        </div>   
    <?php
} 
?>

    <div class="entry-content">

        <?php

            if( is_single() ){

                the_content( sprintf(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
                    wp_kses( __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'blog-way' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ),
                    the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"
 </span>', false )) );

                wp_link_pages( array(
                    'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages :', 'blog-way' ),
                    'after'  => '</div>',
                ) );

            } else {

                echo excerpt_custom_length(20);

            }

        ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
 </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pre_get_posts to exclude the categories you don't want to display in the loop.

```
function exclude_posts_from_specific_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_specific_category' );
```

Or create a new WP_Query and use the Category Parameters.

```
$args = array( 

'category__not_in' => 2 ,

'category__in' => 4 

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you only want to display posts from one category, you would use the category archive.

Comment: Helps but not solves the problem entirely (but that's a start for me ;) Thanks.